# EntityFramework 4 check field exist when SaveChanges

Tags: c#, entity-framework

I'm trying to auto update the "CreateDate" and "UpdateDate" when creating or updating a row by using EntityFramework 4.

I searched here and override the SaveChanges method, it works well.

```
public partial class MyEntities: DbContext
{
    public override int SaveChanges()
    {
        var context = ((IObjectContextAdapter)this).ObjectContext;
        context.DetectChanges();
        var entries = context.ObjectStateManager.GetObjectStateEntries(EntityState.Added | EntityState.Modified);
        foreach (var entry in entries)
        {
            CurrentValueRecord entryValues = entry.CurrentValues;
            if (entry.State == EntityState.Added)
            {
                if (entryValues.GetOrdinal("CreateDate") > 0)
                    entryValues.SetDateTime(entryValues.GetOrdinal("CreateDate"), DateTime.Now);

                if (entryValues.GetOrdinal("UpdateDate") > 0)
                    entryValues.SetDateTime(entryValues.GetOrdinal("UpdateDate"), DateTime.Now);

            }

            if (entry.State == EntityState.Modified)
            {
               if (entryValues.GetOrdinal("UpdateDate") > 0)
                    entryValues.SetDateTime(entryValues.GetOrdinal("UpdateDate"), DateTime.Now);

            }
        }

        return base.SaveChanges();
    }
}
```

**However not every table has UpdateDate,and some even do not have CreateDate field**,

```
entryValues.GetOrdinal("UpdateDate")
```

I don't know how to check if the entry has these fields, and also do not find any

> Try...

method.

Comment: Do you have any control over the entity classes, e.g. the classes where some but now all contain CreateDate and UpdateDate fields?

Comment: Use reflection to check if the property exists. Something like `entry.GetType().GetProperty("UpdateDate") != null`

Comment: I cannot control that.So what I need is when insert any new row do database, check if the entity has "CreateDate",if yes,give it Now, if not, then ignore.

Comment: entry here is CurrentValueRecord type, I tried entry.GetType() in dubug window, it does not work, always return false.

Comment: I find a way to make the target done, but I think it's ugly.<code>var metas = entryValues.DataRecordInfo.FieldMetadata; metas.Any(c => c.FieldType.Name == "UpdateDate")</code> FieldMetadata contain all information of the entity field. I still want to know a better way...

Comment: Sorry I make the format bad....

Comment: Like Nilesh answer, but check the entry.Entity-Property: var prop = entry.Entity.GetType().GetProperty("UpdateDate"); if(prop != null){ prop.SetValue(entry.Entity,DateTime.Now,null);}

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would consider having a base class or an interface for those entities that has CreateDate or UpdateDate

```
public interface IAuditEntity
{
   DateTime CreateDate {get;set;}
   DateTime UpdateDate {get;set;}
}

public class SomeEntity : IAuditEntity
{
   public DateTime CreateDate {get;set;}
   public DateTime UpdateDate {get;set;}
}
```

then in the save function you can check if your entry is an IAuditEntity

```
if (entry is IAuditEntity) 
{
   if(((IAuditEntity)entry).CreateDate ...)
   {
      //... 
   }
}
```